# Instance ocid.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx not found

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Code looks like below.

```
 String instanceId = "ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.abtheljsmrq3yox36wukah52yaeswh6jc4vwjfkc46jxe4nwgnmga7nm7bpq";

        String configurationFilePath = "~/.oci/config.txt";
        String profile = "DEFAULT";

        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");

        AuthenticationDetailsProvider provider =
                new ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider(configurationFilePath, profile);
        System.out.println(provider.toString());
        RequestSigner requestSigner = DefaultRequestSigner.createRequestSigner(provider);

        Client client =
                ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build().register(new SigningFilter(requestSigner));

        WebTarget target =
                client.target("https://iaas.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com")
                        .path("20160918")
                        .path("instances")
                        .path(UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(instanceId));

        Invocation.Builder ib = target.request();
        ib.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = ib.get();
        System.out.println(target.getUri());
```

I double checked the instance ocid in the console.

Output response is as below

```
{  "code" : "NotAuthorizedOrNotFound",  "message" : "instance ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.abtheljsmrq3yox36wukah52yaeswh6jc4vwjfkc46jxe4nwgnmga7nm7bpq not found"}
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Check if
- access_token is expired?
- the user still have access to the instance?

Comment: Why do we need access token here? Private pem file is needed for API Signing.

Comment: The GetInstance operation is available in the Java SDK as a first class operation: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/tools/java/latest/com/oracle/bmc/core/requests/GetInstanceRequest.html -- given that, why are you using the raw request signer for this? Does the call succeed if you use the normal Java SDK operation instead?

You mentioned you checked that the instance is visible in the console, but did you do that using the same user as you're running the above code as? If not, it's possible that the user you're running the code as does not have permissions to this instance.

Comment: I tried with Java-SDK and the result is same. Yes, I used the same user(administrator) for logging into console and as well as in the code(config).

Comment: Do pem file gets expired?

Comment: Yes, keys and have expiry. Expire time of the key is set at key creation time. But a permissions issue wouldn't be due to key expiry, that would be an authentication issue